# How to preprocess timeseries test data to make a classification prediction?

Tags: python, machine-learning, scikit-learn, time-series

When training a classifier model with a timeseries dataset, if you normalize/scale using the min/max of whole training dataset, you are taking into account values of future as well, and in a real scenario you won’t have this information, right? Ok, then you should build your scaler only with your training data:

```
scaler = StandardScaler().fit(X_train)
X_train = scaler.transform(X_train)
X_test = scaler.transform(X_test)
```

But what if the new values are slightly different of the training ones?

Taking this into account, I though in something like:

```
scaler = StandardScaler() # or MinMaxScaler()

scaler_train = scaler.fit(X_train)
X_train = scaler_train.transform(X_train)

scaler_full = scaler.fit(X) # X_train + X_test
X_test = scaler_full.transform(X_test)
```

Or maybe just averaging the mean and the std of train and test to normalize the test input:

```
X_train_mean = np.mean(X_train)
X_train_std  = np.std(X_train)
X_train_normalized = (X_train - X_train_mean) / X_train_std

X_test_mean = np.mean(y_test)
X_test_std  = np.std(y_test)

new_mean =  (X_train_mean + X_test_mean) / 2
new_std  =  (X_train_std + X_test_std) / 2

X_test_normalized = (X_test - new_mean) / new_std
```

What about [this log1p solution](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/preprocessing.html#custom-transformers), which is the same as log(1+x) and which will thus work on (-1;∞)? Or what about [exp normalize](http://timvieira.github.io/blog/post/2014/02/11/exp-normalize-trick/)?

What is the best practice to handle this kind of scenario?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, you should use scikit-learn's [pipelines](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/pipeline.html). This ensures, that when you fit your pipeline on training data, there won't be any [data leakage](https://www.kaggle.com/wiki/Leakage) from the test data.

All your suggestion support data leakage and thus overfitting.

However, let me emphasize that whenn you scale your training data to be between -1 and 1, this will not necessarily hold for your test data. However, your classifier/regression will in general still be able to interpret such inputs. Additionally, you are using the standard scaler, which simply transforms to zero mean and unit variance. Hence, any large/small enough value is still possible but unlikely

Typically, you expect only few points to be outisde that range for you test_set. Otherwise, you didn't sample "representatively" or over time something essential changed. Then you could retrain your algorithm. But this also couldn't matter if the generalization performance of the algorithm is good.

Maybe you should use a [cross validation for time-series sampling scheme](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/cross_validation.html#cross-validation-of-time-series-data)

The shifted log (instead of usual log) is typically only used to allow 0 input values.

Comment: Ok, so I'll build a new model each week to reduce the difference between train and test data.